# Multiple JSTL Versions in Weblogic J2EE App

Tags: weblogic, jstl, jdeveloper, weblogic11g, oracle-adf

Thanks in advance for taking a look :)

I'm hard at work on a J2EE web app (in JDeveloper) and recently added some functionality that required JSTL, and I've hit a little bit of a snag. Whenever I try to deploy my war on Weblogic 11g, I get the following error on the console:

> [02:05:43 AM] Must choose only one of
>   libraries: JSTL 1.0, JSTL 1.2.

I only have one instance of the JSTL library listed under my WebLogic deployments (1.2.0.1).

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Google. I've got nothing.
- Removing all files with the string JSTL in them, in both my Weblogic domain folder and my source folder
- Removing all temp files stored by Weblogic
- Rebooting :)

If you have any ideas on ways to squash this, I'd *really* love to hear them. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that when I added the tags for JSTL in my JSP, JDeveloper suggested that it could automatically add JSTL to my ADF project. Thinking nothing bad could come of this, I let it do its thing and this added an older version of the JSTL to my web.xml file.

The key (I believe) is that I had to remove the web.xml file from my classes directory entirely or else my version of JDeveloper used the old one with the bad JSTL information.

After removing the corresponding jars and references to it and doing a *clean* rebuild I was good to go. Derp.

Thanks for the help though. :)

Answer (score 2):

The [JSTL library is available as a deployable library in Weblogic 11g](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13712/configurejsfandjtsl.htm#i163099) (v10.3.1). If it is not deployed yet, you will have to deploy this onto a Weblogic domain before any application can reference it.

Once deployed, an application can reference the deployed JSTL library through a library reference in weblogic.xml - JSTL once deployed is available as a shared library.

Do keep in mind that using a different version of JSTL will require a solution far more complicated, especially if the JSTL library that came with Weblogic has been deployed.

Comment: I have that library installed in Weblogic already. Thanks though!